# Apache Nifi: Migrating to 1.22

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to migrate from Apache Nifi 1.10 to 1.22.

I see that now there are additional configuration properties for processors which would make earlier processors incompatible.

I searched on the official website, but couldn't found some documentation for this.

Any concrete process to make older processors compatible with latest versions?

Comment: Can you provide the properties that are causing the issues?